# OCaml non decreasing list without List.function

Tags: recursion, ocaml

Update: I can't use any List.function stuff.

I'm new to OCaml and I'm learning this course in which I'm supposed to calculate a list of non decreasing values from a list of values.

So for e.g. I have a list [1; 2; 3; 1; 2; 7; 6]

So function mono that takes in a list returns the following:

```
# mono [1; 2; 3; 1; 2; 7; 6];;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3; 7]
```

I do the following:

```
let rec calculateCheck value lst = (
    match lst with
     [] -> true
    | x :: xs -> (
        if (value < x) then
            false
        else
            calculateCheck value xs
    )
);;


let rec reverse_list lst = (

    match lst with
     [] -> []
    | x :: xs -> (
        reverse_list xs @ [x]
    )
);;

let shouldReverse = ref 1;; 

let cancelReverse somelist lst = (
    shouldReverse := 0;
    reverse_list lst
);;

let rec mono lst = (
    let somelist = ref lst in
        if (!shouldReverse = 1) then
            somelist := cancelReverse somelist lst
        else
            somelist := lst;

    match !somelist with
     [] -> []
    | x :: xs -> (
        if (calculateCheck x xs) then
            [x] @ mono xs
        else
            [] @ mono xs
    );
);;
```

**Problem?**

1. This only works once because of shouldReverse.
2. I cannot reverse the value; `mono list` should return non decreasing list.

**Question?**

1. Any easy way to do this?
2. Specifically how to get a subset of the list. For e.g. for [1; 2; 3; 5; 6], I want [1; 2; 3] as an output for 5 so that I can solve this issue recursively. The other thing, is you can have a list as [1; 2; 3; 5; 6; 5]:: so for the second 5, the output should be [1; 2; 3; 5; 6].

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: For what it's worth, it's difficult to help because the problem statement isn't at all clear. It's easy to calculate a non-decreasing sublist of any list. The empty list is a non-decreasing list. Any list with just one element is a non-decreasing list. Most likely the requirement is much more specific than this. Are you supposed to find one of the (possibly several) *longest* non-decreasing sublists?

Comment: No. Actually, I could've made my self clearer. Sorry about that.

What I effectively want is that to get a backlist. Say for example I need to remove duplicates in a list and only keep the first one. For e.g. for list [1;2;2;4;3;1;3;5], the answer should be: [1; 2; 4; 3; 5]. Consider the second 1 in the list above : there is no way for me to go back in the list and see if 1 exists.

Comment: In this new (completely different?) example, if you just pass your partially computed result along to each recursive call, you don't need to go back in the original list. You can check your partial result to see if the value is already there. Passing your accumulated answer along to each call is a standard technique in FP. (In fact this is a good way to reverse a list, also.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to approach this kind of problem is to force yourself to
formulate what you're looking for *formally*, in a mathematically
correct way. With some training, this will usually get you
a description that is close to the final program you will write.

We are trying to define a function `incr li` that contains the
a strictly increasing subsequence of `li`. As Jeffrey Scoffield asked,
you may be looking for the
[longest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence)
such subsequence: this is an interesting and non-trivial algorithmic
problem that is well-studied, but given that you're a beginner
I suppose your teacher is asking for something simpler. Here is my
suggestion of a simpler specification: you are looking for all the
elements that are greater than all the elements before them in the
list.

A good way to produce mathematical definitions that are easy to turn
into algorithms is reasoning by *induction*: define a property on
natural numbers `P(n)` in terms of the predecessor `P(n-1)`, or define
a property on a given list in terms of this property on a list of one
less element. Consider you want to define `incr [x1; x2; x3; x4]`. You
may express it either in terms of `incr [x1; x2; x3]` and `x4`, or in
terms of `x1` and `incr [x2; x3; x4]`.

- `incr [x1;x2;x3;x4]` is `incr[x1;x2;x3]`, plus `x4` if it is bigger
  than all the elements before it in the list, or, equivalently, the
  biggest element of `incr[x1;x2;x3]`
- `incr [x1;x2;x3;x4]` is `incr[x2;x3;x4]` where all the elements
  smaller than `x1` have been removed (they're not bigger than all
  elements before them), and `x1` added

These two precise definitions can of course be generalized to lists of
any length, and they give two different ways to write `incr`.

```
(* `incr1` defines `incr [x1;x2;x3;x4]` from `incr [x1;x2;x3]`,
   keeping as intermediate values `subli` that corresponds to
   `incr [x1;x2;x3]` in reverse order, and `biggest` the biggest
   value encountered so far. *)
let incr1 li =
  let rec incr subli biggest = function
    | [] -> List.rev subli
    | h::t ->
      if h > biggest
      then incr (h::subli) h t
      else incr subli biggest t
  in
  match li with
    | [] -> []
    | h::t -> incr [h] h t

(* `incr2` defines `incr [x1;x2;x3;x4]` from `incr [x2;x3;x4]`; it
   needs no additional parameter as this is just a recursive call on
   the tail of the input list. *)
let rec incr2 = function
  | [] -> []
  | h::t ->
    (* to go from `incr [x2;x3;x4]` to `incr [x1;x2;x3;x4]`, one
       must remove all the elements of `incr [x2;x3;x4]` that are
       smaller than `x1`, then add `x1` to it *)
    let rec remove = function
      | [] -> []
      | h'::t ->
        if h >= h' then remove t
        else h'::t
    in h :: remove (incr2 t)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot gasche. I guess, I've under the philosophy behind this. I'm still not sure about a couple of things, but I think I'll be able to work them out. Thanks!

Comment: @flippex17: thanks for your kind words. I must warn you that there is a pedagogical trap here: the reason why `subli` is passed to `incr` "in reverse order" in the first function will be obvious to practitioners (it is a classic instance of "passing accumulator arguments" that Jeffrey described), but you may find this troubling as a beginner. This is an idea that will become clear for more practice, but that I feel I failed to explain elegantly.

Comment: Actually on further thoughts, I'm totally lost. Maybe it's sleep; I don't know.

I get the idea of doing the passing my partially computer result to a recursive call but I'am not following the code. Sorry.

Comment: @flippex17: well, it's probably the lack of sleep! I think the second version should be rather easier for beginners to understand, so maybe you should start there.

Comment: @flippex17: I'm fine with replacing the holes by the actual working code if you want to, but I thought you'd rather want to work the solution by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for being considerate gauche. I really appreciate it.

If you would like to give the remaining part of code, it might be helpful for me to understand it completely. I'm not a functional programming guy and that's why some of these things don't make sense sometimes. But, anyway,thanks very much.

Comment: The second code helped me a lot. Thanks a lot for that. It essentially solved one of my main concerns with some of the things permissible by OCaml. Awesome. Thanks.